# assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast (c)

Tags: c

I need to swap two items in the list so that their order changes when rendering.
I have this structures:

```
typedef struct App_Settings app_settings;
struct App_Settings
{
    GList *presets;
};

typedef struct Preset preset;
struct Preset
{
    char* title;
    float freq;
};

app_settings settings;
```

and I write a function to swap next item in list:

```
GList *list_swap_next (GList *list, GList *l)
{
    GList *tmp;

    if (!l)
        return list;

    if (!l->next)
        return list;

    if (l->prev)
        l->prev->next = l->next;
    tmp = l->prev;
    l->prev = l->next;
    l->next->prev = tmp;
    if (l->next->next)
        l->next->next->prev = l;
    tmp = l->next->next;
    l->next->next = l;
    l->next = t;

    if (list == l)
        return l->prev;

    return list;
}
```

and for move up item in gtktreeview:

```
void move_up_button_clicked_cb(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GList *l;
    preset *ps;
    int *row;
        .....................................   
    row = gtk_tree_path_get_indices(path);

    ps = g_list_nth_data(settings.presets, *row);
    g_assert(ps);

    l = g_list_find (settings.presets, (gpointer)ps);
    settings.presets = list_swap_next (settings.presets, l);
        .....................................
```

when compile this get this warning:

```
    warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    settings.presets = list_swap_next (settings.presets, l);
                     ^
```

when I use GINT_TO_POINTER macro to cast list_swap_next

```
settings.presets = GINT_TO_POINTER (list_swap_next (settings.presets, l));
```

no more warning output from compiler but do not know why warning appear without using this "trick"

Why function GList *list_swap_next (GList *list, GList *l) it seems that returns a int?

Comment: Whatever you do, **DO NOT** add a cast to the expression!

Comment: is it settings.preset or settings.presets ... or is `ps = g_list_nth_data(settings.preset, *row);` a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably that there's no prototype for the function that you are variously calling `list_swap_prev()` and `g_list_swap_prev()`, so the compiler assumes that the function returns `int`.

The first step would be to ensure that the naming is consistent (is it `list_swap_prev()` or `g_list_swap_prev()`?)